# Send data to the server when remove app from recent apps programmatically

Tags: android

I have an application that works with the database.

When I exit the application when I click the "exit" button, it sends the data to the server.
There is a bug: when I remove an app from the recent apps, data is not sent to the server.

How can I fix this?

I want the data to be sent to the server when the application is removed from the recent apps.

Comment: Where is the code that sends data to the server? In an `onDestroy()` method? Post the relevant code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could spawn a Service during `onDestroy`, which lets you know when the activity is finished, and send the data from there.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html